# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. (thinkdsp and thinkplot)

Tags: python

I am an amateur programmer. I am trying to use:

`import thinkdsp as dsp`

`import thinkplot as plt`

I have installed the `pip install thinkx` module but I keep getting that error and I don't understand why. I will leave what the console shows down below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Karaokemaker1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import thinkdsp as dsp
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinkdsp.py", line 17, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 185, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 390, in <module>
    from ._minimize import *
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\keigo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I assumed the issue was with the `scipy` because all the following errors come from that module. I checked and I have everything installed properly for the `scipy` module.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Try installing older version ..pip install thinkx==1.1.2

Comment: Do you use Anaconda?

Comment: Try using these two commands `conda remove --force scipy` and 
`pip install scipy`

Comment: @YounessSaadna Thank you very much, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these two commands they will help you:

```
conda remove --force scipy
```

And:

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

Run any command prompt you are using as administrator and then run `pip install lib_name --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same issue than you. Depend on wich version of python you use you should choose a version thinkx. I recommend you to go on the website of thinkx and check out for past udapte. In my case that was with matplotlib 3.3.1 for python 3.7. I went in git bash and used

```
pip install matplotlib==3.0.1
```

and everything worked. I had the same issue with seaborn and it worked.